# Is there a way to search an array inside multiple data attributes of an html element based on a single value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html element that uses arrays inside the data attribute

```
<div data-area='["North America", "United Kingdom"]'>Test</div>
```

I have multiple data attributes pertaining to different "things"

```
<div data-area='["North America", "United Kingdom"]' data-job='["Programmer","Scientist"]'>test</div>
```

**How can I go by searching through all the data attribute tags on the entire element based off of 1 value?**

I'm trying to use a selector rather than looping through each data attribute, Is this possible?

Here is an example plus a fiddle of what I've attempted.

```
// search all data attributes of a div element that contains the given value and apply a hidden class
// this should search every data attribute for "Programmer"
$('[data-*="Programmer"]').addClass('hidden');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pWdSP/1/

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of this solution:

```
$('body *').addClass(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    for (var i in data) if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (data[i].indexOf('Programmer') > -1) {
            return;
        }
    }

    return 'hidden';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pWdSP/4/

It's not optimal since it iterates over all DOM nodes, but I don't see other way to select all the nodes that have `data-*` attribute.

If there are some more precise criterias on what nodes should be checked - it's highly recommended to change a selector accordingly (instead of `body *`)

Comment: If data are stored only in div tags, you could allways add a filter in the selector

Comment: @zerkms.. I thing he means `$('div')` instead of `$('body *')`

Comment: @Sushanth --: ah ok. I've added it in the very end anyway )